# Is the integral average of a Sobolev function on a sphere continuous?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

For $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that every point is a Lebesgue point, we define a version of $u$ to be
$$u(x)=\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{|B_r(x)|}\int_{B_r(x)}u(z)dz$$

Now we define a function
$$f(x)= \frac{1}{|\partial B_r(x)|}\int_{\partial B_r(x)}u(z)d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$$

My question is : Is $f(x)$ continuous？

---

I came across this conclusion in the book "Regularity of the one-phase free boundaries" remark 3.6, so it is probably true. But it obviously doesn't hold for general $H^1$ functions for one can change the values of a Sobolev function on any measure zero sets, so I don't see how every point being a Lebesgue point changes that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems the text only claims that for each fixed $r$, $f$ as defined above, but without lim, is continuous. Just to clarify, is the lim above a typo or not?

Comment: That is a typo. Thank you for pointing it out! @fwd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a consequence of properties of the trace operator; more specifically the following integration by parts/divergence theorem formula:

Let $U\in H^1(\Omega)^n$, where $\Omega$ is a Lipschitz bounded domain; then
$$
\int_\Omega \text{div}U(y)\, dy = \int_{\partial\Omega} U(y)\cdot n(y)\, d\sigma(y),
$$
where $n$ denotes the outward unit normal to $\Omega$, and $\sigma$ is short for $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$.
Notice that when $\Omega=B(x,r)$ then $n(y)= \frac{y-x}{r}$.

Define, for fixed $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $r>0$, and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $U_{x,r}(y):= u(y)\frac{y-x}{r}$. Since continuity of $f$ is a local property, we may as well assume that $u$ has compact support, ensuring that $U_{x,r}\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. By the above formula we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|\partial B(x,r)|f(x) & = \int_{\partial B(x,r)} U_{x,r}(y)\cdot n(y)\, d\sigma(y)= \int_{B(x,r)}[\nabla u(y)\cdot \frac{y-x}{r} + \frac{n}{r}u(y)]\, dy\\
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathbf{1}_{B(x,r)}(y)[\nabla u(y)\cdot \frac{y-x}{r} + \frac{n}{r}u(y)]\, dy.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
At this stage the conclusion follows from the dominated convergence theorem since $\nabla u, u\in L^2$ and $\mathbf{1}_{B(x,r)}\frac{y-x}{r}$ is uniformly bounded (in $x$ and $y$) in compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$. In fact, by the same argument, we see that $f$ is also continuous in $r>0$.

As for how to prove the above divergence theorem, use the extension operator to reduce to the case when $U\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then convolve to get a smooth function for which the usual divergence theorem applies and then pass to the limit using continuity of the trace operator.

Comment: Where is the condition "every point being a Lebesgue point " needed in this argument?
Is it when we use the divergence theorem, we are supposed to write
$$\int_{\Omega} div U(y)dy=\int_{\partial\Omega}Tr(U(y))\cdot n(y)d\sigma$$
But $TrU(y)$ may not equal to $U(y)$ at the boundary, because it is measure zero. And by the condition "every point is a Lebesgue point" we can say they are equal on the boundary and therefore lose the Trace?

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect Lebesgue points to come in (after all there is no limit involved); and looking at the book you reference they don't mention Lebesgue points either, they just state the continuity as is.

Comment: Because if this claim holds for general $H^1$ functions $u$ , shouldn’t this continuity be like : there exists a continuous function $g(x)$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ almost everywhere? Since you can change the value of $u$ on a sphere which have measure zero and thus changing the value of $f$ on a single point, which breaks the continuity at this point. I thought with the Lebesgue points condition we don’t need $f(x)$ to be a ”version” of a continuous function, rather it is itself a continuous function. Did I over think this?

Comment: @paganiac: The way the integral in the definition of $f$ is interpreted is in the sense of traces; this way there's no ambiguity about representatives (they all have the same **trace**, even if they wildly differ on said sphere.)